# State of nested routes in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a route structure like this:

```
this.resource('A',function(){
  this.resource('B',function(){
    this.route('C');
  });
});
```

Is there a way I can check in `A`, which nested route of `B` is currently active?

For usability reasons I have a navigation in `A`, which also holds links for `B.C` and `B.index` But I only want to show one of those two links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application controller has a property on it `currentPath`.  You can use that to find out which path in the router you're currently on.  It's the entire path, so it'd be `A.B.C` or `A.B.index`.

```
App.ColorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:'application',
  atIndex: Em.computed.equal('controllers.application.currentPath', 'colors.index')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nobima/2/edit