# EmberJS - Change property except for index route

Tags: ember.js

I have the following routes, controllers and views:

```
products
products.index
products.product
products.category
products.new
```

I view a list of products on `products`. For all other routes, except for `products.index`, I want to change the property `blurred` on the `products` controller (which blurs the list), so I can view a template on top of it.

Where and how should I do this? Is this something I should put in the view or the controller? I need to be able to determine which route is the child of `products`.

**Update**

I need the list on `products` so it stays in tact, this way the scrollposition is remembered and most importantly, I can 'blur' the product list and show templates on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index route was created for this very purpose.  I'd recommend just moving that list from `products` into the `products/index` template.  Then it'll only show up when you're on `/products` and won't show up any time your on any route/resource deeper.

If you don't want to do that, then you could easily put it in your controller, and follow the pattern shown in this answer: [State of nested routes in EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706232/state-of-nested-routes-in-emberjs/26706761#26706761)

Comment: Kingpin2k, seen a lot of answers of you, keep up the good work! I thought so, but I want the product list to be in the background for some reasons (answer updated). I'll check out the pattern in the link, thanks!

Comment: Would it otherwise be possible to keep the view `products.index` in place without destroying it?

Comment: Ahhhh, for scroll position, that's not a bad candidate for query params btw.  You'd want to use the pattern described in the other answer.